# locating specific columns in a pdf table from R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, pdf, web-scraping

I was wondering how I could locate the **2nd & 3rd columns from left** in the table on the last page (page 18) of the [this pdf document](https://github.com/rnorouzian/m/blob/master/Kang_et_al%20(2015).pdf).

I'm using `pdftools` package, I'm wondering if there is a way to extract the **2nd & 3rd columns from left** which are just numeric data?

```
library(pdftools)
df <- pdf_data("https://github.com/rnorouzian/m/raw/master/Kang_et_al%20(2015).pdf")[[18]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making use of some tidy verse packages this could be achieved like so:

1. Filter for the values in the 2nd and 3rd column. The 2nd column values start at position `x=189`, the 3rd col at `x=252`.
2. Additionally to make sure that we only get the values I first convert to numeric whereby all text gets converted to NA. Note: One of the values has a comma as decimal mark, which I first had to remove.
3. After getting the values I reshape the dataset using `pivot_wider` for which I add a row `id`.
4. Finally I rename the cols.

```r
library(pdftools)
#> Using poppler version 0.73.0
df <- pdf_data("https://github.com/rnorouzian/m/raw/master/Kang_et_al%20(2015).pdf")[[18]]

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

col_x <- c(189, 252)

df %>% 
  mutate(value = str_replace(text, "(\\d+),(\\d+)", "\\1.\\2"),
         value = as.numeric(value)) %>% 
  filter(x %in% col_x, !is.na(value)) %>% 
  select(x, value) %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = x, values_from = value) %>% 
  rename(row = 1, g = 2, se = 3)
#> Warning: Problem with `mutate()` input `value`.
#> ℹ NAs introduced by coercion
#> ℹ Input `value` is `as.numeric(value)`.
#> Warning in mask$eval_all_mutate(dots[[i]]): NAs introduced by coercion
#> # A tibble: 20 x 3
#>      row     g    se
#>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1 0.089 0.179
#>  2     2 0.383 0.257
#>  3     3 0.481 0.355
#>  4     4 0.496 0.356
#>  5     5 0.103 0.335
#>  6     6 0.104 0.257
#>  7     7 0.068 0.289
#>  8     8 0.43  0.359
#>  9     9 1.48  0.351
#> 10    10 1.38  0.257
#> 11    11 0.888 0.388
#> 12    12 0.570 0.314
#> 13    13 0.642 0.39 
#> 14    14 1.16  0.364
#> 15    15 0.341 0.432
#> 16    16 0.607 0.299
#> 17    17 0.473 0.361
#> 18    18 0.472 0.423
#> 19    19 0.902 0.368
#> 20    20 0.245 0.363
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is complicated, and after wasting quite a bit of time fiddling with pdf_data() output, thought it might help to show how to extract and manipulate vectors.

```
library(pdftools)
library(stringr)
df <- pdf_data("https://github.com/rnorouzian/m/raw/master/Kang_et_al%20(2015).pdf")[[18]]
df <- df[stringr::str_detect(df$text, "\\d"),]
data.frame(se = df$text[df$x == 189], g = df$text[df$x == 252])
```

Comment: It’d be useful to edit your answer to include additional explanation. What sets this approach apart from the accepted answer?